# Trying to use awk to parse lscpu output but can't get it right

Tags: linux, awk, s390x

Essentially what I want is to extract the byte size of the L3 cache from lscpu. The tricky part is that the units lscpu uses is not consistent across versions and what I need has to work with all versions (including the versions before the --bytes option was available). lscpu from what I can see will either use K, KiB, M or MiB so that is what I'm trying to parse.

Here is what lscpu outputs:

```
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                16
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-15
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    1
Socket(s):             16
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 60
Model name:            Intel Core Processor (Haswell, no TSX, IBRS)
Stepping:              1
CPU MHz:               2299.998
BogoMIPS:              4599.99
Virtualization:        VT-x
Hypervisor vendor:     KVM
Virtualization type:   full
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              4096K
L3 cache:              16384K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-15
Flags:                 fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl xtopology eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq vmx ssse3 fma cx16 pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand hypervisor lahf_lm abm invpcid_single ssbd ibrs ibpb tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid xsaveopt arat md_clear spec_ctrl
```

And this is what I have so far but can't seem to finish it off.

```
$ lscpu | awk '/L3 cache:/{print $3$4;next};/(M|MiB)$/{printf "%u\n", $3*(1024*1024);next};/(K|KiB)$/{printf "%u\n", $3*1024;next}'
0
32768
32768
4194304
16384K
```

Any ideas how to tweak my awk command to get this working?

Edit:
My expected output would just be:

```
16777216
```

Comment: `16777216` would be the output if the input was `16384KiB` but it's not, it's `16384K` and so the output should be `16384000` since 1K is 1000 while 1KiB is 1024. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_prefix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Really Cyrus' answer is the optimal, but if you're set on awk, try this:

```
 awk -F: 'BEGIN{def=1024}/^L3/{if($2~/M/){def=def*def}; printf "%u\n", $2*def}'
```

Comment: This looks to be exactly what I need. Couldn't uses the solution from Cyrus, left details why in comment response. Thanks!

Comment: 1 question I do have going through is what is the purpose of using gsub here? Quick testing without it doesn't appear to change anything and I can't really pick up on what it is doing

Comment: Well, I'm just making sure that awk doesn't try to multiply M or K ...

Comment: Apparently it doesn't bother awk if there are trailing alphas =}

Comment: Right, when doing any numeric operation awk just ignores every char starting the first one it can recognize as not being part of a number. btw `def=def*def` = `def*=def`

Answer (score 1):

Get level 3 cache (L3) in bytes:

```
getconf LEVEL3_CACHE_SIZE
```

Comment: getconf can't be used since it appears to pull it's info from `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cache/` which is incomplete on some OS architectures (specifically RHEL s390x) so it just returns 0. lscpu pulls info from other sources so it is able to give values

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    mult["K"]   = 1000
    mult["KiB"] = 1024
    mult["M"]   = mult["K"]^2
    mult["MiB"] = mult["KiB"]^2
}
sub(/^L3 cache:/,"") {
    smbl = $NF
    sub(/[^[:alpha:]]+/,"",smbl)
    print $0 * mult[smbl]
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
16384000
```